Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string "" to bytes calldata requested
I'm doing the course of Patrick Collins to learn about programming in Solidity; but some libraries from Chainlink has been changed since 2 years ago. So, when I try to compile the code I have the next problem:
Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string "" to bytes calldata requested.

I know the problem is in the function checkUpkeep or performUpkeep. The code is the following one:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/KeepersVRFConsumer.sol";

error Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__NotOpen();
error Raffle_UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalnce, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    }

    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    address private s_recentWinner;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;

    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
        }
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__NotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));

        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes calldata /*checkData*/
    ) public override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
        bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval;
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle_UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }

        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 /*requestId*/,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }
}

I found another post with a similar problem that mine, but solutions given there don't work for me.

In the parameter of checkUpkeep() function, you've to changes bytes calldata to bytes memory. Also, you can make this function as view and return the required values.
So, the revised checkUpkeep() function would be:
function checkUpkeep(
    bytes memory /*checkData*/
)
    public
    view
    override
    returns (
        bool upkeepNeeded,
        bytes memory /* performData */
    )
{
    bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
    bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval;
    bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
    bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
    upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
    return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0");
}

Explanation:
By changing the parameter type to bytes memory, it's handling the byte array as a copy in memory, which allows it to work correctly with empty byte arrays, whereas bytes calldata is more optimized for reading data from transaction input and might not handle empty byte arrays as expected.

Thanks, it works. I'm gonna to try to understand why :)

Great. I've added the explanation as well. Kindly please accept the answer if it helped you.
